# React avoid all child rerendering

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So I have a master component which has several children, I simplified it with the example below

```
const Master = ({ c1props, c2props }) => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

    return <div>
        <div>{count}</div>
        <Child {...c1props}/>
        <Child {...c2props}/>
    </div>
}
```

So here my problem is that when I update only the state "count", the  components are re-rendering, which is a problem because they are pretty heavy.
I was thinking about using useMemo() inside Child as a way to avoid those uneeded re-rendering but I don't if it's the best idea.
Any idea how to address this ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const MemoizedChild1 = React.memo(Child1, isEqual);
const MemoizedChild2 = React.memo(Child2, isEqual);
```

Then you use it like this:

```
const Master = ({ c1props, c2props }) => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

    return <div>
        <div>{count}</div>
        <MemoizedChild1 {...c1props}/>
        <MemoizedChild2 {...c2props}/>
    </div>
}
```

where isEqual is a lodash function that deeply tests the equality of props.

Generally you can use memo like this:

```
function MyComponent(props) {
  /* render using props */
}
function areEqual(prevProps, nextProps) {
  /*
  return true if passing nextProps to render would return
  the same result as passing prevProps to render,
  otherwise return false
  */
}
export default React.memo(MyComponent, areEqual);
```

Read more on [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo).

useMemo is a hook that memoizes a value, and memo can give you control about whenever to render your component or not.

Comment: ok so useMemo() is the right way to go I guess it's the shouldComponentUpdate() replacement, I'll give it a try thank you

Comment: You are welcome, it is React.memo and not useMemo, useMemo is a hoc meanwhile memo is a hoc that prevent your component from rendering if your comparator function returns true (the next and previous props are equal)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to avoid the usage of memo you may consider to split your Master, and create another `Counter` component which contains the count state:

```
const Master = ({ c1props, c2props }) => (
  <div>
    <Counter />
    <Child {...c1props}/>
    <Child {...c2props}/>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: yes but the example is simplified here, the real one is updating one child and not the other, but yeah it would be a good option otherwise